# Autocompleting parentheses in Visual Studio Code for Go

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

While using of Visual Studio Code I've noticed that when I write function from autocomlete it never autocomlete with parentheses. For example:

```
fmt. //now select a function Print(a ...interface{}) from autocomplete

fmt.Print //why the  parenthesehas have not been inserted automaticaly?
```

Is it always so in VS code or it is somehow related to the golang setting for VS code? Is there a way how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your VSCode settings (JSON) add the following line;

`"go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest": true`

Or if you are viewing your preferences/settings as the UI version, search for `useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest` and set it to true. This will

- Add parentheses to the tailing end of function names.
- Complete function suggestions with parameter signatures, including the variable types.

---

There is also the setting of `go.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggestWithoutType` which does the same, but omits the variable types.

---

You need the Visual Studio Code (Google Go Team maintained) Go extension installed [which can be found here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go)

Comment: When I select the autocomplete, my cursor moves to the end of the line instead of inside the parentheses. Really annoying. Any advice?