# Visual Studio Code Autocomplete Add Parentheses After Method in .js File

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I type `console.lo` in a `.js` file in Visual Studio Code, I can hit `Enter`, and autocomplete will change my line to `console.log`. However, I would also like autocomplete to add parentheses. This question [was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087036/autocompleting-parentheses-in-visual-studio-code-for-go) using the Go programming language. I tried adding `js.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest` as well as `javascript.useCodeSnippetsOnFunctionSuggest`. Neither of these work. I also tried `useCodeSnippetsOnMethodSuggest` as [suggested here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/276), but that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the setting: `Javascript > Suggest : Complete Function Calls`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by searching for "Complete Function Calls" in VS Code's settings, and checking `JavaScript > Suggest: Complete Function Calls`. Thanks Mark for the suggestion.